# Unslave a redis slave

Tags: redis

I have a setup of 3 instances in a failover cluster, one master and two slaves. All monitored by sentinels. At one point I decide I don't need one slave, and I want to reuse that redis instance for something else, what commands to I issue?
I tried running `slaveof no one` on that slave, but it's enslaved again in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentinels remember forever the slaves they have seen, in order to reconnect them when they return after a crash or a network partition.

For the sentinels to forget the slave to remove, Redis' doc says "you need to send a SENTINEL RESET mastername command to all the Sentinels: they'll refresh the list of slaves within the next 10 seconds, only adding the ones listed as correctly replicating from the current master INFO output."